# How can i add html email template for email confirmation in asp.net mvc5 identity 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

By Default asp.net mvc5 Identity 2 email confirmation comes with this code.

```
   await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
```

But i want to add a html email template.So how can i do this ? Thanks

Comment: Email template an ASP.NET Identity are two totally different things. What do you want to use? Emails, or ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: I want to change the confirmation email UI.

Comment: You will then work with the HTML content of your application. Did you try editting the HTML, that will be rendered?

Comment: Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>
I want this message in a html view.but how i call that view from await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can store the html tag in a variable and then pass that variable to the method UserManager.SendEmailAsync() method.

```
string message = "<h3>Your Email Tempalte</h3>";
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", message);
```

For more details please check this link: http://forums.asp.net/t/2026812.aspx?How+can+i+add+html+email+template+UI+for+email+confirmation+in+asp+net+mvc5+identity+2+

Comment: If using SMTP mail in asp.net, you have to set the MailMessage's .IsBodyHtml property to true.  Otherwise, at least in some email clients, the user will see the HTML code, not the desired presentation.